# Cómo reordenar una matriz en Python de modo que las columnas que comienzan con una determinada letra vayan al final

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, ordenamiento

Teniendo una matriz cuya primera sublista sea una lista de los títulos de las columnas de la matriz (lista de listas), reordenar la matriz original de modo que las columnas que tengan como título de columna una string que empiece con U vayan al final

```py
matrix = [['U2', 'U1', 'X'], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]] #matriz de ejemplo
```

A modo de ejemplificar he colocado aqui una matriz pequeña pero esto podría aplicarse a matrices más grandes que también tengan columnas para ordenar, por ejemplo...

```py
matrix = [['C',   'X', 'B', 'U1', 'L2', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4',  'X5'], 
          ['+M', 'U1',   8,  1.0,    0,  2.0,  1.0, -1.0,    0,     0], 
          ['+M', 'X4',   2,    0,    0,  1.0,  1.0,    0,  1.0,     0], 
          [ 0.0, 'U2',   8,     0,  1.0,  1.0,  2.0,    0,    0, -1.0]]
```

De modo que se obtenga esta matriz

```py
matrix = [['X', 'U1', 'U2'], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]] #output esperado
```

Este es mi código pero no funciona bien, porque salvo por la lista de títulos de columnas, el resto de listas quedan tan solo con un único elemento y eso esta mal.

```py
matrix = [['U2', 'U1', 'X'], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]

# Identificaría los índices de las columnas que comienzan con "U"
u_columns = []
for i, title in enumerate(matrix[0]):
    if title.startswith('U'):
        u_columns.append(i)

# Elimina las columnas que comienzan con "U" de la matriz original
u_columns.reverse()  # Revertir la lista de índices para eliminar las columnas correctamente
u_columns_headers = [matrix[0][i] for i in u_columns]  # Guardar los títulos de las columnas eliminadas
for i in u_columns:
    for row in matrix:
        del row[i]

# Concatenaría las columnas eliminadas al final de la matriz original
for header in u_columns_headers:
    matrix[0].append(header)

# Aquí crearía una nueva matriz combinando los títulos de columna con la matriz reordenada
new_matrix = [matrix[0]] + matrix[1:]

# Imprime la nueva matriz
print(new_matrix)

# Opcionalmente podría colocarse así para que se visualice mejor
for row in new_matrix: print(row)
```

Este es el output incorrecto que da este código:

```py
[['X', 'U1', 'U2'], [0], [0], [1]]
```

Tener en cuenta que para el ordenamiento solo importan los elementos de la sublista de índice 0; es decir, de la fila de títulos de columna o headers. No importa si dentro del resto de filas i + 1 en donde estan los elementos de la matriz hay o no elementos con 'U'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: esta respuesta utiliza las funciones zip y sorted. Si no se te está permitido usarlas, vendría bien aclararlo en la pregunta. Si ese es el caso, modificaré mi respuesta.

---

**codigo**

Una forma por la que podés lograr ese objetivo de manera sencilla sería:

```
matrix = [['U2', 'U1', 'X'], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]

matrix = sorted(zip(*matrix), key=lambda x:x[0].startswith("U"))

matrix = list(zip(*matrix))

print(matrix)
```

Que produce:

```
[('X', 'U2', 'U1'), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)]
```

Que, si bien no es el resultado mostrado en la pregunta, si es lo que se quiere lograr.

**Explicación**

Este código puede parecer incomprensible, pero no te preocupes, me enfocaré a explicarlo parte por parte.

```
zip(*matrix)
```

La función `zip(iter1, iter2, iter3, ...)` junta el item n-esimo de cada iterable (como una lista) en una sola tupla. El "*" significa "pasá cada item del iterable siguiente en forma de argumentos".

Por ejemplo, `zip("abc", "123")` produce algo parecido a `("a", "1"),("b", "2"),("c", "3")`.

```
sorted(zip(*matrix), key=lambda x:x[0].startswith("U"))
```

sorted, como dice su nombre, ordena el iterable. Si el argumento key se pasa, cada item es "transformado" por dicha función antes de hacer la comparación interna.

En este caso, transformamos cada tupla del zip en True o False. Pero me dirás "eso no se puede comparar". Resulta que, al menos en Python, True = 1 y False = 0, y por lo tanto se pueden comparar. Debido a la equivalencia antes mencionada, los elementos falsos aparecerán primero en la lista y los veraderos después. Si dos items "son iguales", se agregan a la nueva lista en el orden en el que aparecen (de ahí la diferencia en el resultado).

```
list(zip(*matrix))
```

Esto vuelve a darle a la lista el estilo anterior, donde cada titulo estaba en la misma lista.

---

Lo que basicamente estamos haciendo es "leer" la lista "de arriba a abajo", ordenarla y volver a hacer que se lea de izquierda a derecha.

Comment: Si se puede intentaria evitar el uso de librerias externas, pero si no hay otro modo creo que estaria bien, almenos para llegar a una solucion

Comment: Mi respuesta no usa librerías externas

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio. Tambien gracias por tiempo de explicarmelo

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar numpy pq es muy útil con matrices. es este output lo que querías ?

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [['C', 'X', 'B', 'U1', 'U2', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'],
          ['+M', 'U1', 8, 1.0, 0, 2.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0, 0],
          ['+M', 'X4', 2, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 0],
          [0.0, 'U2', 8, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0, 0, -1.0]]
matrix = np.array(matrix)
sort_by = "U"
index = 0
new_matrix = matrix
columns = None
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    if sort_by in matrix[0][i]:
        tmp = matrix[:, i]
        if columns is None:
            columns = np.vstack(tmp)
        else:
            columns = np.hstack((columns, np.vstack(tmp)))
        new_matrix = np.delete(new_matrix, i - index, axis=1)
        index += 1
new_matrix = np.hstack((new_matrix, columns))
print(new_matrix)
```

output:

```
# sort by U
[['C' 'X' 'B' 'X1' 'X2' 'X3' 'X4' 'X5' 'U1' 'U2']
 ['+M' 'U1' '8' '2.0' '1.0' '-1.0' '0' '0' '1.0' '0']
 ['+M' 'X4' '2' '1.0' '1.0' '0' '1.0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0.0' 'U2' '8' '1.0' '2.0' '0' '0' '-1.0' '0' '1.0']]
# sort by X
[['C' 'B' 'U1' 'U2' 'X' 'X1' 'X2' 'X3' 'X4' 'X5']
 ['+M' '8' '1.0' '0' 'U1' '2.0' '1.0' '-1.0' '0' '0']
 ['+M' '2' '0' '0' 'X4' '1.0' '1.0' '0' '1.0' '0']
 ['0.0' '8' '0' '1.0' 'U2' '1.0' '2.0' '0' '0' '-1.0']]
```

Comment: Hay un problema, si hubiese otra columna U o si en lugar de ordenar los U ordenase las columnas que empiesen con L, tan solo apareceria una sola columna U o L en lugar de todas las que haya de manera ordenada, al parecer las elimina si hay un  U1 y U2, U3,...

Comment: he editado mi respuesta. espero que te ayude

Comment: muchas gracias por aditarlo